# Best approach to displaying a scrollable grid of pictures in Flex Mobile App

Tags: mysql, image, actionscript-3, apache-flex

In a Flex Mobile Application, I have a situation where I need to dynamically display a grid of like 50X50 pictures that can be scrolled though. The pics are stored in a mysql database.

I don't really know enough about the DataGrid or the TileLayout. Or if anyone knows of any other classes I should be reading up on to better solve this issue.

So, Basically like I said, I'm looking for any Flex/Actionscript-3 Class Ideas, examples, tutorials, ideas, feedback or anything to get me pointed in the right direction for this issue. I'm really stumped on how I can/should be doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough:

```
<fx:DataGroup dataProvider="{yourImageURLs}" width="100%" height="100%"
   itemRenderer="yourCustomImageRenderer">
   <fx:TileLayout requestedColumnCount="2" />
</fx:DataGroup>
```

That should get you started.

Comment: Thanks! Got me on the right track, I read about those components and figured something out. But I'm having trouble getting it working if i update my dataprovider during runtime. but it works fine if i set up an array in the declarations. Mind taking a quick look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301551/flex-4-itemrenderer-not-working-if-dataprovider-is-updated-during-runtime-any-id

Comment: edit:nvm about my other question I linked too. Apparently you have to .refresh the array collection. I didn't realize that was necessary.

Comment: brybam, it isn't necessary *unless* you change the ArrayCollection.source property (the underlying array).  If you do, you need to call refresh.  It might be simpler to just create a new ArrayCollection and update that: `yourBindableVar = new ArrayCollection(underlyingArray);`